# How to create a new file

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

PhoneGap - How to create a new file in `assets/www/example/hallo.text`
my error is `"Error  fileSystem"`

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function fail() {
  confirm('Error  fileSystem');
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
  fileSystem.root.getFile("file:///android_asset/www/example/hallo.text", {
    create: true
  }, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
  fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
  writer.write("hallo");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML file system API operates in a sandboxed file system.  You cannot reference absolute paths with respect to the full filesystem; instead, all of your Web app's file system exists in a browser-generated subdirectory inside the device's real firesystem.

This was done deliberately, for security reasons, so that Web apps can only overwrite or read files that they have created.  Otherwise, any page on the Web might read all the private contents of your whole hard drive.

You should use an unqualified file path like `www/example/hallo.text` (assuming those directories exist) or simply `hallo.text` to create the file in your sandboxed file system.  Do not use an absolute `file:` path.

Additionally, your error function, `fail`, is probably being supplied with an argument with error info. Try adding an argument to the function like `function fail(error) ...` and printing out `error` for more debugging info.

Comment: Is that when you use a path starting with `file://` or without?

Comment: with file:// getFile("file:///android_asset

Comment: Then you need to remove it, as I said in my answer.  Unfortunately, you cannot accomplish what you are trying to do (access a specific file on the real filesystem) with HTML5 or Phonegap.  All file operations in HTML5 are in a sandbox file system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure "you" have rights to write in the destination folder (your device may need to have the root permissions to write in some folders).

After that, follow the instructions from here: http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html

Comment: The OP wants to know how to create a file *in Phonegap*, an HTML5-to-native-app bridge.  The OP's application is written in JavaScript, not native Android code.